# UrlMkGetSessionOption acquire wrong UserAgent

Tags: c++

when use UrlMkGetSessionOption to acquire IE default UserAgent, I get the string "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)".But my IE Browsertype is IE11 and not in the compatible mode.What should I do to acquire the right string?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably testing on a Webbrowser and your feature control keys are not set so it is setting ie7 as default browser.
Check this key and change the value to "11001" for IE11:

```
-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (or HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
   SOFTWARE
      Microsoft
         Internet Explorer
            Main
               FeatureControl
                  FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
                     yourApplication.exe = (DWORD) 00009000
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx#browser_emulation

Note: if your os is 64 bits and your app is 32 bits, you have to take this path instead: SOFTWARE/**WOW6432NODE**/MICROSOFT...